# No Video Signal on boot

Tags: gpu-driver

Trying to troubleshoot a no video signal issue. Running Ubuntu mate 18.04 LTS.
When trying to boot this evening was getting no video signal
I have dual Titan Volta GPU's and tried switching the HDMI cable to the 2nd GPU. No difference.

Not getting any error messages on the motherboard on boot.
I know my monitor is fine because I can plug my laptop into the 2nd HDMI input.
Never experienced this before.
Is it possible either a recent software and or driver update has hijacked the video out signal? Is there some keyboard combination I can try on boot?
Any feedback welcome!